# Getting can't modify frozen string when using string.insert

Tags: ruby

This is a quick question. I have the following ruby code, which works fine.

```
  def add_zeros number, zeros
    number = number.to_s
    zeros_to_add = zeros - number.length
    zeros_to_add.times do
      number = "0#{number}"
    end
    number
  end
```

But if I replace

```
number = "0#{number}"
```

With

```
number.insert(0, "0")
```

Then I get TypeError: can't modify frozen string, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? I can't reproduce that error in 1.8.6, 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 on OSX. It works fine for me. Another way around on this: is there any other code that might be affecting the state of `number`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using ruby 1.8.7 on mac os, this error occurs when I use it in testing

  def test_zeros
    {"43544"=>"43544", "344"=>"00344", 5=>"00005", 100=>"00100"}.each_pair do |input, expected|
      string = @bs.add_zeros(input,5)
      assert_equal(string.class, String)
      assert_equal(string, expected, "Should be #{expected} but is #{string}")
    end
  end

where I have it operating from within a class with the @bs instance

cheers

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the passed argument `number` is already a frozen string to start with, then `number = number.to_s` won't change a thing and you won't be able to modify it in place (with `number.insert`):

```
add_zeros("24".freeze, 10)  # => TypeError: can't modify frozen string
```

Creating a new string from it (`"0#{number}"`) is not a problem, of course.

The reason why your string is frozen is subtle. When you use a string as a hash key, Ruby will make a copy of it and freeze it:

```
s = "hello"
h = {}
h[s] = :world
key = h.keys.first  
key.equal?(s)  # => false  (Ruby made a copy)
key.frozen?    # => true   (Ruby automatically freezes the copy)
```

Anyways, as a general rule, a method should not modify its arguments.

In this case, you probably want to use `rjust`:

```
24.to_s.rjust(10, "0") # => "0000000024"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

I wasn't aware that the string I was passing it was a frozen string (but now I think of it, are strings passed in as an argument are automatically considered `frozen`??). I think I may need to learn more about this!! I wanted to add the number.to_s for the cases when an integer was passed although sometimes it might be a string.

But I will look at more info on frozen strings, thanks so much for the advice it is appreciated.

Thanks also for the tip on rjust, that is very helpful, I will be using this instead!

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot to say why your string was frozen in the first place. Check my updated answer.